# How to append value to a system property using command line

Tags: java, command-line-tool, system-properties

When setting property value via command line, the whole value will be replaced. Example:

```
$ java -XshowSettings:properties ...
Property settings:
<...snip...>
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
<...snip...>
```

```
$ java -XshowSettings:properties -Djava.library.path=foo ...
Property settings:
<...snip...>
    java.library.path = foo
<...snip...>
```

BTW, actual value of `java.library.path` is just a string with paths separated by colon. So, how to *append* to a property value, instead of replacing it?

UPD. Let's imagine we don't have a way to manipulate env vars for the sake of clarity.

UPD 1. By "using command line" I mean using command line switches of the tool, in this case `java`. Why not to use env vars? Because env vars is basically managed by the shell, not `java` command. I mean, the `java` command doesn't set any of suggested env vars (like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `JAVA_HOME` or anything other), they are set by shell. There is circumstances when you can't use env vars, for example when invoking `java` command from other tools/editors/IDEs *without* shell.

So, to summarize, what I want to do is: take current value of property (managed internally by JVM) and *append* to this value using *only* `java` command switches like `-D` or whatever it has.

Comment: Please explain more about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The value of an appropriate environment variable is prepended to `java.library.path`.

On OS X, with Oracles 1.8.0_201, for instance, that variable is `JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH`, so:

```
$ JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=foo:bar java -XshowSettings:properties
...
    java.library.path = foo
        bar
        /Users/tdavies/Library/Java/Extensions
        /Library/Java/Extensions
        /Network/Library/Java/Extensions
        /System/Library/Java/Extensions
        /usr/lib/java
        .
```

I don't know what the behaviour is on other platforms. I was surprised that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` wasn't used on OS X.

Comment: For most unix operating systems, it will use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. For Windows, it will use PATH.

Comment: Actually this is not appending using command line but rather env wars

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of "command line".

Answer (score 0):

**bash**:

```
  java -XshowSettings:properties  -Djava.home=${JAVA_HOME}:mytest1111
```

**output**:

`java.home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home:mytest1111`

Comment: same as this, you must make the env var

Comment: Note that this is bash syntax, not cmd syntax. In cmd, it would be `java -XshowSettings:properties  -Djava.home=%JAVA_HOME%;mytest1111` (semivolon instead of colon and `%%` instead of `${}`).